# Upload picture selected using UIImagePickerController

Tags: iphone, uiimagepickercontroller, asihttprequest

I'm trying to upload the picture selected using UIImagePickerController. The UIImagePickerController gives UIImage object that I can display in a view, but it doesn't give a path (may be it does and I'm looking at wrong place).

I'm using ASIFormDataRequest to upload content, but this would need path to the picture to upload it.

Any suggestion ?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have UIImage with you than you don't need local path for image to upload, you can upload it using following code.

```
NSData *imgData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(YourUIImageObject);

NSURL *url = @"yourURL";

ASIFormDataRequest *currentRequest = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
[currentRequest setPostFormat:ASIMultipartFormDataPostFormat];
[currentRequest setRequestMethod:@"POST"];
[currentRequest addData:imgData withFileName:@"file" andContentType:@"image/png" forKey:@"yourFileNameOnServer"]; //This would be the file name which is accepting image object on server side e.g. php page accepting file
[currentRequest setDelegate:self];
[currentRequest setDidFinishSelector:@selector(uploadImageFinished:)];
[currentRequest setDidFailSelector:@selector(uploadImageFailed:)];  
[currentRequest startSynchronous];


-(void)uploadImageFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest*)request
{
     //Your request successfully executed. Handle accordingly.
}

-(void)uploadImageFailed:(ASIHTTPRequest*)request
{
     //Your request failed to execute. Handle accordingly.
}
```

Please leave comment in case of any doubt.

Hope it helps.