# Sending UIImage from UIImagePickerController to PHP server using ASIFormDataRequest

Tags: php, ios, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller, asihttprequest

In a current project, I have implemented an `UITableViewController` that collects certain data and send it to the backend server by the users request.
This all works fine and dandy.. however, I have problems uploading the image.

As soon as I get the image om the `UIImagePickerController` and send it, the server seems to have a problem. If I encode it as JPEG, PHP doesn't seem to understand it... if I encode it as PNG the whole request seems to get screwed up.

If I, however, select a any other image that exists in the project (e.g. some background image) the upload process works perfectly! That is the weird part. As soon as I use an image from the UIImagePickerController, it doesn't work... eventhough I do get the image (see addSubview in code, which works).

This is my code:

```
@interface ServiceViewController ()

@property (nonatomic) UIImage *image;
[...]

@end

@implementation ServiceViewController

@synthesize image = _image;
[...]

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    self.image = [[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] copy];

    [self.tableView reloadData];

    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

- (void)sendToApi
{
    // Send post data
    NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", API_BASE_DOMAIN2, @"requestservice"];
    urlString = @"http://localhost/api/public_html/requestservice";

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];

    ASIFormDataRequest *request = [[ASIFormDataRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
    [request setUseKeychainPersistence:YES];
    [request setPostValue:[self.problems objectAtIndex:self.problem] forKey:@"problem"];
    [request setPostValue:[self stationName] forKey:@"station"];
    [request setPostValue:self.otherInformation forKey:@"information"];
    [request setPostValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:self.lock] forKey:@"lock"];
    [request setUploadProgressDelegate:self];
    [request setDidFinishSelector:@selector(didCompleteRequestService:)];
    [request setDidFailSelector:@selector(processFailed:)];
    [request setDelegate:self];
    [request setRequestMethod:@"POST"];

    // Upload an image
    [request addData:[NSData dataWithData:UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self.image, 0.9)] withFileName:@"img.jpg" andContentType:@"image/jpeg" forKey:@"picture"];


    UIImageView *view = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:self.image];
    [view sizeToFit];
    [self.view addSubview:view];

    [request startAsynchronous];
}

- (void)setProgress:(float)newProgress {
//    [prgressView setProgress:newProgress];
    NSLog(@"New progress: %f", newProgress);
}

- (void)didCompleteRequestService:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{
    NSLog(@"Request completed");
    NSLog(@"Result: %@", request.responseString);
}
```

Server side:

```
    var_dump($_FILES);

    if ($this->_aPicture !== null) {
        $sTarget = DIR_SERVICE . $this->_sFileNamePrefix . ".jpg";

        var_dump($this->_aPicture);
        var_dump($sTarget);

        if (!move_uploaded_file($this->_aPicture['tmp_name'], $sTarget)) {
            $this->returnHttpError(500);
        }
    }

    $this->_writeDataToFile();
```

This is my result:

```
2013-03-21 00:04:04.859 AppName[15598:c07] New progress: 0.000000
2013-03-21 00:04:04.862 AppName[15598:c07] New progress: 1.000000
2013-03-21 00:04:04.863 AppName[15598:c07] Request completed
2013-03-21 00:04:04.863 AppName[15598:c07] Result: array(1) {
  ["picture"]=>
  array(5) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(7) "img.jpg"
    ["type"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["tmp_name"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["error"]=>
    int(1)
    ["size"]=>
    int(0)
  }
}
array(5) {
  ["name"]=>
  string(7) "img.jpg"
  ["type"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["tmp_name"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["error"]=>
  int(1)
  ["size"]=>
  int(0)
}
string(58) "/Users/paulp/Sites/api/service/K98XQPo7zx.jpg"
Sending error: 500
```

I have tried a bunch of different things, such as:

- [How to upload image that was taken from UIImagePickerController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12138484/how-to-upload-image-that-was-taken-from-uiimagepickercontroller)
- [Upload picture selected using UIImagePickerController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9559227/upload-picture-selected-using-uiimagepickercontroller)
  and some more.

I have not changed to e.g. MKNetworkKit since there is no time or budget for that (yet), so that is not a solution.

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, my former code worked perfectly...
it turned out that it were my PHP settings which were incorrect. In my `php.ini` file, the config value `upload_max_filesize` was set to the default of `2M`. After changing it to `200M` it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

Save the selected image

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)img editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editInfo {

    //Save selected image to document directory
    jpgPath = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents/Test.jpg"];
    [UIImageJPEGRepresentation(img, 1.0) writeToFile:jpgPath atomically:YES];
    [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

then use `ASIFormDataRequest`'s `setFile:forKey` method to send image to server

```
ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
if (jpgPath.length > 0) {
     [request setFile:jpgPath forKey:@"image"]; 
}
```

Comment: Thats not a bad idea at all, I'll give it a go a little later today. thnx

Comment: Tried it, got the same problem.

Comment: I found the issue... my PHP settings. `upload_max_filesize` was set to 2M and the file was 5M. Took me 4 hours to figure that out :(

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, it works perfect for me:

```
[request addData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) withFileName:@"image.png" andContentType:@"multipart/form-data" forKey:@"image"];
```

Comment: As I mentioned above, the PNG representation screws up the whole form for some reason. Using that, the PHP end doesn't seem to recieve any POST data.

Comment: Let me ask our server-side programmer.

Comment: As written on the top, you experience the problem related to upload_max_filesize limitation.
Error = 1 means following:
"The uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini"
Default value for this setting is 2M. Seems you try to upload more that 2M. Edit php.ini and restart php (or apache, if you use it).

Comment: @Karisters You read my answer correctly. That was exactly what happened, which I answered already to the question. Thanks though.